# Unable to launch Spyder due to FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, spyder

The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3208, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3084, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 828, in setup
    self.workingdirectory = WorkingDirectory(self, self.init_workdir, main=self)
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\workingdirectory.py", line 159, in __init__
    self.chdir(workdir)
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\workingdirectory.py", line 296, in chdir
    self.refresh_plugin()
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\workingdirectory.py", line 204, in refresh_plugin
    self.save_wdhistory()
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\workingdirectory.py", line 234, in save_wdhistory
    encoding.writelines(text, self.LOG_PATH)
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\encoding.py", line 236, in writelines
    return write(os.linesep.join(lines), filename, encoding, mode)
  File "C:\Users\Shubham\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\encoding.py", line 227, in write
    with open(filename, mode) as textfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '%USERPROFILE\\.spyder-py3\\workingdir'
```

Comment: Can you describe what you’ve done so far?  Is this a new install? After an update? Out of the blue?

Comment: And how are you lunching it? What version of python are you using? Is it in the base environment?

Comment: before today it was working fine, but all of sudden i was not able to open anything from the navigator. So i reinstalled anaconda but still nothing is happening.

Comment: @anishtain4 version 3.6.5..

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a bug in Spyder and we'll fix it in our **3.3.0** version, to be released later in June/2018.